# What Minecraft version removed this feature?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

When a creative mode world was created, you would get items automatically in your hotbar, like bricks, wood planks, etc. Can anyone tell me what version removed this?

Answer (score 3):

[1.2.0](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Creative#History) in Bedrock Edition, [1.3](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Creative#History) in Java

Answer (score -4):

This functionality has not been removed. By going into gamemode creative you still have the option to get all the items you want